# Python - comparing data match from different columns

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to process data from a DataFrame containing various columns like "Start", "End", "Identifier", and "SW Value". This is what one row looks like on excel.

Since the SW value contains the Identifier `Start`, I want to say it's a match. I don't know how to implement this. i also want to see if the start value matches after rounding to 4 decimal but i don't know how to do that.

[image]

i tried to convert both identifier and SW value to lowercase before the check to make sure it wasn't a problem because of case sensitivity but it still says no match instead of yes.

```
def is_identifier_contained(identifier, sw_value):
    if identifier.lower() in sw_value.lower():
        return True
    else:
        return False

# Check if identifier is contained in sw value
if start_numerical_count == 1 and end_numerical_count == 0 and identifier_count == 1:
    identifier = str(row["Identifier"])
    sw_value = str(row["SW Value"])
    if is_identifier_contained(identifier, sw_value):
        table.at[i, "Identifier in SW Value"] = "Yes"
    else:
        table.at[i, "Identifier in SW Value"] = "No"
else:
    table.at[i, "Identifier in SW Value"] = "N/A"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use vectorized functions for this.

```
#default to False boolean, can set as a string if you want
df['match'] = False

#find rows matching the identifier, set those rows 'match' value to True boolean
df.loc[df['SW Value'] == identifier, 'match'] = True
```